# An Application of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

As an application of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we would like to evaluate the following limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_1^{n}\frac{1}{\displaystyle\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^nx^{1/n}}\ \mathrm dx.
$$
We realized that to put the limit the inside of the integral we need to find an integrable function $g(x)$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{1}{\displaystyle\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^nx^{1/n}}\right| \leq g(x).
$$

We did this. But the boundary of the integral also depends on $n$. At this point, we do not know what we need to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Using
$$ (1+z)^n\ge \binom{n}{2}z^2 $$
for $z>0$, one has
$$ (1+\frac{x}{n})^n\ge\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}=\frac12(1-\frac1n)x^2\ge\frac14x^2$$
for $n\ge2$. Then define
$$ f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^nx^{1/n}}\,1_{[0,n]} $$
to estimate $f_n$ as
$$ |f_n(x)|\le\frac{4}{x^2} $$
for $x\ge1$ and then one can use LDC.

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$
\int_1^{n}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^nx^{1/n}}dx
=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^nx^{1/n}}\,1_{[0,n]}\,dx.
$$
If your $g$ does not depend on $n$, you are done.